# Open file from SSL-enabled SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint, ssl, sharepoint-2007

I have a SharePoint web app that has SSL enabled and a desktop application accessing the Document Library.
If I try opening a document without SSL enabled, the URI looks something like:
`\\[SiteUrl]\DavWWWRoot\Sites\[SiteName]\[DocumentPath]`

and I can successfully open and save the file.
However, after enabling SSL, the URI is
`\\[SiteUrl]@SSL\DavWWWRoot\Sites\[SiteName]\[DocumentPath]`

and I get an "Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed." exception.

How can I keep SSL and still be able to access files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used StreamReader instead of XmlReader to open the file. The "Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed." exception does not get thrown this way.

Answer (score 0):

can you access the URL via https:// instead of webdav?

Comment: yes, but I am using the OpenFileDialog to browse the collection and it automatically translates the URL from https to webdav